# Magento 1.7.0.0 CE FishPig - Ultimate Category Excluder Extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fishpig

I'm using FishPig's free WP integration plugin and have purchased their "Ultimate Category Excluder". I've installed from what I can see correctly since I can see it available and is enabled in Magento.

Then, I downloaded the actual category excluder WordPress plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ultimate-category-excluder/, installed, and set the category I wanted to exclude. The FishPig extension should allow this plugin to work from what I understood communicating with the author.

However, category I set to be excluded refuses to not be excluded and shows everything.

I've installed everything fine from what I can see. Compilation and Caching is disabled since it is on a development server at the moment but I compiled, cleared all caches, and reindexed everything and redisabled that stuff.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this? I couldn't find documentation for this extension, the archive didn't come with a readme, nothing... I didn't expect that from FishPig but maybe I'm blind and missed something...

Best Regards,

George

Answer (score 1):

Looked over my previously asked questions today and realized that this problem was resolved but I did not answer it.

Anyway, the solution was to reinstall WordPress from scratch and import data into the installation. The client's website had the old WP install on different server and I imported to same server as Magento. However, realized later on that the DB AND files were modified by previous developer in some fashion and the best approach to resolving this issue was to reinstall WP fresh, copy over content, and stuff from old DB to new.

Finally, after that was done installed the category excluder plugin and it worked with FishPig.

I had assistance from FishPig's Ben and am very thankful. I would recommend this extension (free) and any pay for ones from this author. Great Support, great people!